# "System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added." when trying to order an in-memory LINQ query by a LINQ association

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

We are doing a query against an in-memory collection of LINQ data objects. The wrinkle is that we are ordering by a column in a related table whose records have not necessarily been loaded yet (deferred loading:)

```
Dim oPkgProducts = _
From b In oBillPkg.BillProducts _
Where b.Successful.GetValueOrDefault(Common.X_INDETERMINATE) = _
    Common.X_INDETERMINATE _
Order By _
    b.ProductFromCache.ProvisionCodePriority.ProvisionPriority Ascending _
Select b
```

We logged the following error in production when the code tried to call Count() on this query:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with
>   the same key has already been added.
>   at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource
>   resource) at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey
>   key, TValue value, Boolean add) at
>   System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.SetCurrent(MetaType
>   type) at
>   System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.Find(MetaType
>   type, Object[] keyValues) at
>   System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetCachedObject(MetaType
>   type, Object[] keyValues) at
>   System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.DeferredSourceFactory`1.TryGetCached
>   Object(Object[] keyValues, T& cached)
>   at
>   System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.DeferredSourceFactory`1.Execute(Object
>   instance) at
>   System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.DeferredSourceFactory`1.DeferredSource.GetEnumerator()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source) at
>   System.Data.Linq.EntityRef`1.get_Entity()
>   at
>   PackageManagement.Product.get_ProvisionCodePriority()
>   in
>   C:\Projects\DLLs\DotNet35\PackageManagement\PackageManagement.designer.vb:line
>   14431 at
>   ProvisionEngine.BillPackageProvision.*Lambda$*_12(BillProduct
>   b) in
>   C:\Projects\DLLs\DotNet35\ProvisionEngine\BillPackageProvision.vb:line
>   394 at
>   System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[]
>   elements, Int32 count) at
>   System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[]
>   elements, Int32 count) at
>   System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source) at
>   ProvisionEngine.BillPackageProvision.ProvisionPackage(BillPackage
>   oBillPkg, Boolean bRecursiveCall) in
>   C:\Projects\DLLs\DotNet35\ProvisionEngine\BillPackageProvision.vb:line
>   397

The confusing part is that when the operation was automatically retried a few seconds later, it succeeded. And since this is the only time we've seen the exception (the code runs fine the rest of the time) it is not going to be easy to reproduce.

Some background: "ProductFromCache" is a helper property that uses [Pete Montgomery's technique for implementing a LINQ to SQL cache](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/caching-the-results-of-linq-queries/). The code could be rewritten to use the default LINQ .Product property too. I don't think this is part of the problem because the stack trace shows that the exception is happening inside .NET System libraries. I think the exception is happening when the .ProvisionCodePriority property is called -- this returns a record from a table associated to the product table. LINQ seems to be trying to cache the result of this deferred load in a generic Dictionary object. But for some reason, the Dictionary already contains the specified key.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Comment: obiously the problem isn't in linq but in that helpere you are using

Comment: Do multiple threads write to the dictionary at the same time?

Comment: Well the Dictionary in this case is inside LINQ to SQL's DataContext/query apparatus. It's not something I created but some sort of internal helper object. I surmise that it's being used for L2S's [identity cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/07/01/linq-to-sql-tips-9-understanding-datacontext-s-internal-caching.aspx) (such that when an entity with the same primary key has already been loaded from the database, it is simply retrieved from the dictionary for the current request, avoiding another roundtrip.) Note that this is not the same as the Pete Mongomery's FromCache.

Comment: ...cont'd: The problem here is that L2S seems to be stumbling on a particular key and thinks it is adding it for the first time when in fact it's already in the lookup dictionary.  As I said below, it seems that this issue has not recurred in our Production environment in the last six months, and the code has been called thousands of times. So I am willing to chalk it up to cosmic rays ;-)